# Rails 4 + Postgres = Missing milliseconds in model timestamps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, activemodel

I have timestamps in my model created with `t.timestamps` command in the migration.

If I look in the database directly, the milliseconds are stored correctly. But when I fetch the object the milliseconds are not there.

```
Model.first.updated_at.iso8601(3)
 => "2013-09-28T13:43:58.000Z"
```

**Why isn't the milliseconds fetched from the database?**

Comment: How are you trying to display them on your view. I would assume that's where they are not showing.

Comment: @Vezu I'm using ActiveModelSerializers to generate JSON. But that doesn't matter, I can't seem to find the milliseconds even in the console like in the question.

Comment: I use Jbuilder to create my JSON i use with a mobile app. I do get miliseconds created_at":"2013-09-17T12:37:21.741Z"

Comment: What happens if you write what I did above in the console? Are you using Rails 4? Are you using PostgreSQL?

Comment: I get => "2013-09-05T05:49:27.449+01:00" yes, i am on rails 4

Comment: Then its really weird that I get it without milliseconds?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was not Rails, it was the Ruby 2.0.0-p247 binary on OS X that had a bug:

https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2189

Comment: I would like to add that the same bug referenced here effects other areas where millisecond precision is expected, not just the scenario described in the SO question.